# c# socket, передача строки между сервером и клиентом

Tags: c#, сокет

Суть работы, клиент делает запрос серверу на получение данных, сервер принимает запрос и в ответ отправляет длинный string

В моём случае строка передается, но передается она каждый раз с разной длинной т.е. "привет"/ "приве" / "при" / "привет".
Складывается впечатление, что клиент не дожидается, когда строка дойдет полностью и начинает её обрабатывать. Можно ли как-то это исправить, чтобы строка приходила всегда полностью?

В клиенте получение ответных данных выглядит так: `int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);`

Сервер:

```
    // Создаем локальную конечную точку
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
                // Создаем сокет
                Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    // Связываем сокет с конечной точкой
                    socket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                    // Переходим в режим "прослуивания" соединения
                    socket.Listen(1);
                    // Ждем соединение. При удачном соединении создается новый экземпляр socket, связанный с этим соединением
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Socket handler = socket.Accept();
                        // Массив, где сохраняем принятые данные.
                        byte[] recBytes = new byte[1024];
                        int nBytes = handler.Receive(recBytes);
                        String msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recBytes, 0, nBytes);
                        var parsedMsg = CommandParser.ParseMessage(msg);

                        switch (parsedMsg[0])    // Определяемся с командами клиента
                        {
                            // отправка длинной строки
                            case Commands.CinemaSessions:
                             handler.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetCinemaSessions()));
                                break;
                        }

                        // Освобождаем сокеты
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
```

Клиент:

```
public static string SendMessageFromSocket(string command, string message)
        {
            var messageForSend = CommandParser.CreateCommand(command, message);

            // Буфер для входящих данных
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            // Соединяемся с удаленным устройством

            // Устанавливаем удаленную точку для сокета
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Global.IpAddress, Global.Port);

            Socket sender = new Socket(Global.IpAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Соединяем сокет с удаленной точкой
            sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);

            byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageForSend);

            // Отправляем данные через сокет
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

            // Получаем ответ от сервера
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);

            // Освобождаем сокет
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();

            //ответ от сервера
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя так просто читать данные с `TCP` соединения. `TCP` гарантирует отправку данных в правильной последовательности, но не гарантирует, что вы будете получать данные такими же порциями, какими отправляет их вторая сторона.

Если вы хотите отправлять сообщения разной длины, сначала отправьте длину сообщения. Для самого простого примера это может быть 1 байт. И дальше в цикле вы должны читать с сокета, пока не прочитаете все сообщение.

Comment: В моём случае ошибка оказалась в объеме буффера для входящих данных, когда данные были  больше чем буффер, то и возникали ошибки) А так, данные стабильно передаются